# How to upgrade Website from dotnet framework 4 to 4.6.2 on production

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Currently hosted asp.net website on production has target .Net framework 4. I want to upgrade this website with .Net framework 4.6.2.Can anybody explain me how to change target framework with 4.6.2 and any impact on existing code.